# Developing Distributed application in C++ using RPC (linux)

Tags: c++, linux, rpc, middleware

I'm developing a distributed application in C++ and need a middleware for that . I have done a comparative and my conclusions are :

1. CORBA . It's dead :-(
2. MQ options. Like ZeroMQ+MessagePack or ProtocolBuffers + Something for RPC. So new that there are not a RPC mature library for C++.
3. ZeroC/ICE. A really good one but not a choice for licences issues.
4. Dbus. Not so distributed as is for local desktop and with a performance issue for big payload (patch kernel for that in development).
5. RPC. Old one but for now this is my best choice.

So, what do you think for a distributed application in C++ in the XXI century (2014).

What about Apache Thrift?? any experiences C++ and Apache Thift RPC?

Thanks.

Comment: as a fast comment try to look at Data Distribution Service, is an open standard middleware: http://portals.omg.org/dds/ (never used it though)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [CppRemote](http://www.cppremote.com/) library.  It is easy to use and object oriented.  You write IDL using c++ macro and no need external compiler.  Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Comment: It reminds me the way that ZeroMQ+MessagePack+MessagePack-RPC works but better (congrat) , gonna do some test.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends upon the application, and expected bandwidth betwesen nodes, and needed scalability (aiming a datacenter supercomputer with millions of cores in hundred thousands of hosts is not at all the same as aiming a few desktops on gigabyte ethernet).

Consider also [MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/); if you don't need a lot of bandwidth, consider simpler textual protocols like [json-rpc](http://json-rpc.org/)

Comment: It's not going to be that big and I don't like a messages system but an RPC solution.

Comment: JSON RPC is an RPC solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Communications Engine (Ice) is a modern and up-to-date RPC Mechanism which supports many languages. You can download it [here](http://www.zeroc.com/download.html). Much of the Ice APIs are defined in Slice which is the specification language for Ice.

Slice (Specification Language for Ice) is the fundamental abstraction mechanism for separating object interfaces from their implementations. Slice establishes a contract between client and server that describes the types and object interfaces used by an application. This description is independent of the implementation language, so it does not matter whether the client is written in the same language as the server.

Slice definitions are compiled for a particular implementation language by a compiler for example for C++.

Comment: As I said , even when ZeroC/Ice maybe is the best option, it's no an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Storm, it's distributed RPC: http://storm.incubator.apache.org/